# estimatedHeight methods causing overlapping UITableView section headers and odd header animations

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` with multiple sections. I use `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and detect the selected row in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to animate the height change of selected cells. This works well, but because I use things like DynamicType, the height calculation can be time consuming, so I have implemented the great `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:` to provide a roughly-constant value to speed up the process.

The problem is that when I use the `estimatedHeight` methods for either rows or section headers, the section headers animate strangely. The headers will drop ~50 pixels and then animate up over the content of the cells. Sometimes, the header gets duplicated in the middle of the cell and never goes away. Remove **both** `estimatedHeight` methods, and things are fine. If either `estimatedHeight` method is present, even if they return the same value as the `heightFor` method, the strange animations happen.

No-frills code that reliably reproduces this error is below, and the complete sample project is at currently available at this [public Dropbox link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4820776/StrangeTableViewHeaderCells.zip). Is there any way to keep the `estimatedHeight` methods that greatly reduce height calculation time while preventing these header anomalies? Xcode 6.1.1, iOS 8.1.2.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

const CGFloat HEADER_HEIGHT = 24;
const CGFloat EXPANDED_HEIGHT = 150;
const CGFloat COLLAPSED_HEIGHT = 70;
NSString * const REUSE_IDENTIFIER = @"BasicCellReuseIdentifier";

@implementation ViewController

/*
 * Cell appearance.
 */

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:REUSE_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %ld, Row %ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    return (cell);
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %ld", (long)section]);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (2);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return (2000);
}

/*
 * Heights.
 */

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (HEADER_HEIGHT);
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] isEqual:indexPath])
        return (EXPANDED_HEIGHT);
    return (COLLAPSED_HEIGHT);
}

/*
 * Actions.
 */

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /* Animate cell height changes */
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

/******************************************************************************
 ******** FIXME: Disable estimatedHeight methods and things work fine. ********
 *****************************************************************************/

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (HEADER_HEIGHT);
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] isEqual:indexPath])
        return (EXPANDED_HEIGHT);
    return (COLLAPSED_HEIGHT);
}

@end
```

[image: Overlapping section header]

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem when using beginUpdates/endUpdates to make height changes to a cell that has an estimatedHeight set.

Comment: @DanielWilliams No, I ended up changing UI in a later version of my app to remove animated cell height changes. I might suggesting using a CollectionView to see if this goes any better there.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that this is the best solution but it is better then a loop:
You could keep an array that tells if each index if expanded or not. Essentially index 1 would be slot 1 in the array and it would have a true value to show it is expanded.

That or if these cells are derived from a local object you could add a expanded attribute.

Comment: The code is basic to demonstrate the issue I asked about: odd animations with section headers.